Using Azure Devops deploy release to multiple repos
so I am trying to deploy changes from my CoreDb repo , that's a SQL database project to a release. This release would just be script changes that multiples countries would grab into their repos and make changes from there. I can't deploy directly to all the countries because some countries are on different versions than others.
The CoreDb repo is a SQL project as well that contains all the common files for all countries. I only handle the CoreDB repo, the country's local dev teams will handle their repos.
I created my CoreDB repo with a build pipeline and a release pipeline. I'm not sure how to  connect the process of the country repos retrieving these releases (by version) for their own repos.
I was thinking either:

create stages for every country in my CoreDb release pipeline that will manually be deployed, but then I'm not sure how we would handle merges in the sql files or will files get replaced?


Create a deployment task of some sort in my release pipeline that would execute scripts that would call the git commands to pull my CoreDb repo into their country's repo. The countries would update the script with their country name and what version they need and the script would do the git commands.


I already tried using git to pull the Core DB repo into my test project and merge the changes, which works, but my boss wants the process to be more streamlined, because we have 27 countries.

Are the repos all DevOps git? Are they in same DevOps organization or different? When conflict happens during the merge, will source repo file(CodeDB) used to replace all country repo? Can you share two repo sample?

All the repos will be DevsOps git. I think they will be in a different devops organization. When a merge conflict occurs, I want the CoreDb to replace the country repo with a changescript file so they can know the changes.

You can follow below steps to achieve:
1.Prepare your source code in CoreDb repo.  You can use the build pipeline to publish the artifact which contains the files.
For example, i copied the target files and exclude .git folder below. You need to prepare the code base to your requirement.


Consume the build artifact in release pipeline:



In the release stage:

a). git clone the 1st target repo.

You can get the target repo url following doc here. Add the Personal accesstoken in the url as above. And add pat as variables in 1st stage:


b)With task copy files, replace the target files, tick overwrite option to use source files.

c) Push changes to target repo, and generate the changescript.

Script content below:
cd targetrepo1
git config --global user.email "tester1@example.com"
git config --global user.name "tester1"

# Check for changes before commit
git status

git add .
git commit -m "Copy from source repo"
git push origin main

# Generate change script
git diff --name-status HEAD~1 HEAD > changescript.txt

# Display change script content
echo "The file changes are below:"
cat changescript.txt

The files are copied to target repo and checked changescript content:

You can clone the stage and change the target repo, and pat ...etc in new stage, so that it can deploy to other target repo.

